# Convert x, y, z to heading and angle

Tags: c++, math

I am not so good at maths.

I am converting the heading and angle to x, y, z coordinates using the below code.

```
double x  =-((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::sin(DEG_TO_RAD(heading)))/std::sqrt(std::pow(1000,2)+std::pow(((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::cos(DEG_TO_RAD(heading))),2)+std::pow(((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::sin(DEG_TO_RAD(180-heading))),2));
double y = (1000/std::sqrt(std::pow(1000,2)+std::pow(((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::cos(DEG_TO_RAD(180-heading))),2)+std::pow(((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::sin(DEG_TO_RAD(180-heading))),2)))*(angle/std::sqrt(std::pow(angle,2)));
double z =-((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::cos(DEG_TO_RAD(180-heading)))/std::sqrt(std::pow(1000,2)+std::pow(((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::cos(DEG_TO_RAD(180-heading))),2)+std::pow(((1000/std::tan(DEG_TO_RAD(angle)))*std::sin(DEG_TO_RAD(180-heading))),2));
```

I want to now do the reverse or is it even possible

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1210570 ?

Comment: Or this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions